# Do I need one or more Entities if my json look like this? Spring BOOT

Tags: json, database, jdbc, spring-data, entity-relationship

I am new to spring boot and Java. I have a question about json data as I am not sure if I need 2 tables (Entities) or 1. 
I do believe I need one to Many relationship for Order Entity to Item Entity and then One to One relationship for Item to ItemAlternateId Entity. but I am not sure if I am correct.

```
{
  "orderId": "ORD001",
  "orderReferenceCode": "ABCD",
  "messageId": "123",
  "message": "Hello",
  "DeliverAt": "2016-08-25",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": "1234",
      "itemBaseType": "skuMin",
      "itemAlternateId": {
        "skuLegacy": "L0472851",
        "barcodeAsin": "ASIN29384845",
        "barcodeEan": "EAN3928445"
      },
      "itemDescription": "Beans",
      "quantityOrdered": 30,
      "priceOrderedAmount": 1.34
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need two or maybe event three for itemAlternateId. You maybe should start learning relational database modelling

Comment: yeah! I am reading into it. Yeah I do believe now that I need 3 tables Order, Item, ItemAlternate with Order and Item having 1:M realtionship and Item and ItemAlternate having 1:1. Thanks for the answer